# Setting particular Interval of time for DatePicker (Minimum and Maximum Time) Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

Hi Im trying to limit my date Picker values within a particular Period of time as per my Backend Response. I refer many Links but nothing helps me, here is my code.

```
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .time

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let today = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

    let preprTime = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "PREPARATION_TIME")!
    let start = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "START_TIME")!
    let end = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "END_TIME")!
    //Prints--> preprTime = 30 Mins.,  start = 08:00:00, end = 23:00:00


    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"
    let startDt = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(today) \(start) z")
    let endDt = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(today) \(end) z")

    //Prints--> startDt = 2017-11-02 08:00:00 +0000, endDt = 2017-11-02 23:00:00 +0000

    let mins = preprTime.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234567890").inverted)

    let startTime: Date = startDt!.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(Int(mins)! * 60))
    let endTime: Date = endDt!.addingTimeInterval(-(TimeInterval(Int(mins)! * 60)))

    //Prints--> startTime = 2017-11-02 08:30:00 +0000, endTime = 2017-11-02 22:30:00 +0000

    datePicker.minimumDate = startTime
    datePicker.maximumDate = endTime

    //Prints--> datePicker.minimumDate = 2017-11-02 08:30:00 +0000, datePicker.maximumDate = 2017-11-02 22:30:00 +0000
```

I Think I almost done, it prints the correct values, but the datePicker's Minimum and maximum dates are not set properly. Which means the datePicker's minimumDate(time) is today 2.00 PM and maximumDate(time) is today 11.59 PM. I dont know where im doing mistake, can someone help me to trigger this...? 
Thanks in Advance....!

Comment: I think, you are facing locale problem, Printed date is stating +0000, it looks like UTC time, My advice is to change date to current Locale before calculating startTime & endTime.

Comment: @DipakKacha, Can you share any sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting your mimimumDate and maximumDate based on the difference in timezone

The difference is

```
let gmtDiff = TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()
```

My timezone is +5:30, so I need to subtract it from start and end time

```
var startDt = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(today) \(start) z")
startDt = startDt?.addingTimeInterval( -TimeInterval(gmtDiff))
var endDt = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(today) \(end) z")
endDt = endDt?.addingTimeInterval( -TimeInterval(gmtDiff))
```

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't get you how can I implement this....? Can you make an edit with code..

Comment: Hi, It working fine when i run this on Simulator, whereas it giving a crash when run on Device  --->                                                                                    
 let startDt = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(today) \(start) z") at this line im getting nil value. Could you help me...?